# How can I write a python program to calculate the monthly interest rate but display yearly outputs?

Tags: python

Write a program that calculates and prints the balance of a loan over time. The program must ask user for the following (in order):

The amount of the loan, i.e. principal (float).
The annual interest rate as a fraction of 1.0 (float).
The monthly payment amount that the user has arbitrarily chosen (float; the amount is not calculated).
The term of the loan in years (int).
The loan is principal-and-interest and the program simulates paying a fixed amount off the loan every month. The interest is calculated monthly before the fixed payment.

Note that the program must calculate principal and interest changes monthly but only prints an update every year. For this question, it's fine for the balance to go negative.

Running the program should look exactly like the following:

```
Principal? 100000
Interest rate? 0.055
Monthly repayment? 1000.00
Term in years? 5
Year       Opening      Closing
   0    100,000.00    93,333.62
   1     93,333.62    86,291.20
   2     86,291.20    78,851.53
   3     78,851.53    70,992.21
   4     70,992.21    62,689.55
```

The output must be formatted to 2 decimal places and alignment as shown.. The numbers are 11 characters wide, with comma separators and two decimal places. I wrote the below program but I am not getting the required output:

```
principal = float(input('Principal? '))
interest = float(input('Interest rate? '))
payment = float(input('Monthly repayment? '))
Term = int(input('Term in years? '))
payment = 1000
n = 1
p = 0
opening = principal
m_opening = 0
m_closing = 0
rate = 0
closing = 0
i=0
year = 0
m = 0
print(f'Year       Opening      Closing')
for i in range (Term):
  if year == 0:
    while n<=12:
      rate = opening*interest/12
      closing = opening - (payment-rate)
      opening = closing
      n = n+1
    m = closing
    opening = principal
    print(f'  {year:2}   {opening:11,.2f}  {closing:11,.2f}')
    year = year+1
  else:
    n=1
    while n<=12:
      rate = opening*interest/12
      closing = opening - (payment-rate)
      opening = closing
      n = n+1
    print(f'  {year:2}   {opening:11,.2f}  {closing:11,.2f}')
    year = year+1
```

My output is coming as below:

```
Principal? 100000
Interest rate? 0.055
Monthly repayment? 1000
Term in years? 5
Year       Opening      Closing
   0    100,000.00    93,333.62
   1     93,333.62    93,333.62
   2     86,291.20    86,291.20
   3     78,851.53    78,851.53
   4     70,992.21    70,992.21
```

Comment: I don`t understand exactly your question. Maybe you need a dataframe as an output and not strings printed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the opening of the year after the first year, of not you are modificating opening variable each time. Also you dont need m = closing and opening = principal. Find below slighly modificated working code.

```
principal = float(input('Principal? '))
interest = float(input('Interest rate? '))
payment = float(input('Monthly repayment? '))
Term = int(input('Term in years? '))
payment = 1000
n = 1
p = 0
opening = principal
m_opening = 0
m_closing = 0
rate = 0
closing = 0
i = 0
year = 0
m = 0
print(f'Year       Opening      Closing')
for i in range(Term):
    if year == 0:
        while n <= 12:
            rate = opening * interest / 12
            closing = opening - (payment - rate)
            opening = closing
            n = n + 1
        # m = closing
        # opening = principal
        print(f'  {year:2}   {principal:11,.2f}  {closing:11,.2f}')
        year = year + 1
    else:
        n = 1
        yearOpening = closing
        while n <= 12:
            rate = opening * interest / 12
            closing = opening - (payment - rate)
            opening = closing
            n = n + 1
        print(f'  {year:2}   {yearOpening:11,.2f}  {closing:11,.2f}')
        year = year + 1
```

Output:

[image]

Hope that helps!